# Using Git via command line is buggy, but bash works fine?

Tags: git, bash, command-line, nant, dvcs

We're trying to modify out NANT build script to pull changes from our remote Git repository and then publish from a local repository on the build server. While testing out the commands I would need to run I discovered that using Git.exe directly appears to be buggy.

I can do a fetch via the windows command line and it correctly updates the remote branches to point to a newer revision than my local branches. However, when I then try to merge those remote changes into the local branch, it claims I have uncommitted changes and will not let me merge. If I run "status" it tells me I have no changes and it's ready to be fast-forward merged with the remote branch.

If I switch over to the regular Git Bash it works fine. I can fetch and merge all day long with no weird issues about mysterious uncommitted changes that I can't see.

Comment: Please can you post the commands and error messages that you see here, not in some 3rd party video site. I did try, but I got bored. One thing to note, if you want to compare like with like you should use the same working tree in each example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I am using the same working tree...

You have to specify the `.git` on the end when passing in the `--git-dir` option.

Comment: The error is just what I said. Exact phrasing is "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: _list of files updated in fetch_ Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge."

Comment: I didn't really follow the video but it certainly looked like you were using `...\Git\bin` as the working tree in one version. I may be mistaken, I didn't really understand what was going on.

Comment: @CharlesBailey \Git\bin is the working directory of Git.exe which is where we are passing in the arguments. Git Bash is a running Git console. The program itself is also located in \Git\Bin.

From the Windows CMD we pass the git directory as an argument. However, the Git Bash is run in the context of the git directory. They should be doing the same thing, but one appears to fail on the merge.

Comment: Did you pass `--work-tree` to git in the `cmd` version or were you using the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Bingo. No I was not. Thanks a million! PS - Post that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify work tree when doing the merge:

```
git --git-dir=c:\code\klas\.git --work-tree=c:\code\klas merge origin/master
```

Edit: Just noticed that Charles Bailey mentioned it in a comment and I ensure that I was not trying to kill steal :)